# Llamar a una tabla desde una primary key compuesta

Tags: mysql, c#, sql

Necesito tomar los datos de una tabla con dos primary key a otra, intento referenciar a una de las key desde otra tabla pero me arroja este error:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'PEDIDO' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__DETALLE__6477ECF3'.

Desarrollado en *visual studio 2019 .net C#* aquí el sql.

```
CREATE TABLE PEDIDO(ID INT NOT NULL, NUM_PEDIDO INT NOT NULL, 
                NOM_PROD VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, MESA INT,
                PRIMARY KEY(ID, NUM_PEDIDO),
                FOREIGN KEY (NOM_PROD) REFERENCES PRODUCTOS(NOMBRE));


CREATE TABLE DETALLE(ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, FECHA TIME NOT NULL, NUM_PEDIDO
                INT, TOTAL  INT, VENDEDOR VARCHAR(50), MED_PAGO VARCHAR(20),
                PROPINA INT, DESCUENTO INT, VUELTO INT,
                FOREIGN KEY (NUM_PEDIDO) REFERENCES PEDIDO(NUM_PEDIDO));
```

De antemano gracias.

Como llamar a una tabla con llaves compuestas desde otra tabla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una FK tiene que referenciar TODA la PK de otra tabla. No tienes dos PK, tienes **una** PK compuesta. Ese es el concepto clave.

Entonces, como la PK es UNA y tiene dos campos, la FK tiene que referencias los dos campos en dos campos propios de la tabla. Así como no tuvo sentido hacer una PK de sólo un campo, no tiene sentido buscar integridad referencial con sólo una parte de la PK.

```
CREATE TABLE DETALLE(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    FECHA TIME NOT NULL,
    PEDIDO_ID INT,     -- añades el campo para tener el ID de la FK
    NUM_PEDIDO INT,    -- conservas el otro campo
    TOTAL  INT, 
    VENDEDOR VARCHAR(50), 
    MED_PAGO VARCHAR(20),
    PROPINA INT, 
    DESCUENTO INT, 
    VUELTO INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (PEDIDO_ID, NUM_PEDIDO) REFERENCES PEDIDO(ID,NUM_PEDIDO)  -- referencias los dos campos
);
```

Ahora, no sabemos qué definición en tu sistema requiere que sea una PK compuesta y por eso no lo cuestiono. Esta es la solución al problema técnico :)

Comment: estimado, muchas gracias, pensaba que la llamada de esas llaves era mas simple, pero ya entiendo que se deben llamar a ambas, cree esa llve compuesta porque necesito enviar varios productos bajo el mismo numero de pedido a la tabladetalle